# Allowing multiple CSS classes to use the same JS function (Slick Carousel)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slick.js

I am trying to implement Slick slider multiple times on the same page, with each instance using "Slider Syncing". Now the issue I'm having is that with my code below, the synced text adjusts with both sliders:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Test</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./slick/slick.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./slick/slick-theme.css">
</head>
<style type="text/css">
  html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }

  * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  .person {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0px auto;
  }

  .person img {
    width: 100%;
    margin:auto;
  }

  .slider {
      width: 90%;
      margin: 20px auto;
  }

  .slick-slide {
    margin: 0px 20px;
    opacity: 0.5;
  }

  .slick-slide img {
    width: 100%;
  }

  .slick-prev:before,
  .slick-next:before {
      color: black;
  }

  .slick-center {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  }
</style>
<body>

  <section class="person">
    <div><img src="img/people/jobs.jpg"></div>
  </section>
    <section class="regular slider">
      <div><img src="img/1.jpg"></div>
      <div><img src="img/2.jpg"></div>
      <div><img src="img/3.jpg"></div>
      <div><img src="img/4.jpg"></div>
      <div><img src="img/5.jpg"></div>
      <div><img src="img/6.jpg"></div>
      <div><img src="img/7.jpg"></div>
      <div><img src="img/8.jpg"></div>
      <div><img src="img/9.jpg"></div>
    </section>

    <section class="slider-for slider">
      <div>1</div>
      <div>2</div>
      <div>3</div>
      <div>4</div>
      <div>5</div>
      <div>6</div>
      <div>7</div>
      <div>8</div>
      <div>9</div>
    </section>

    <section class="regular slider">
      <div><img src="img/1.jpg"></div>
      <div><img src="img/2.jpg"></div>
      <div><img src="img/3.jpg"></div>
      <div><img src="img/4.jpg"></div>
      <div><img src="img/5.jpg"></div>
      <div><img src="img/6.jpg"></div>
      <div><img src="img/7.jpg"></div>
      <div><img src="img/8.jpg"></div>
      <div><img src="img/9.jpg"></div>
    </section>

    <section class="slider-for slider">
      <div>1</div>
      <div>2</div>
      <div>3</div>
      <div>4</div>
      <div>5</div>
      <div>6</div>
      <div>7</div>
      <div>8</div>
      <div>9</div>
    </section>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="./slick/slick.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('ready', function() {
      $(".regular").slick({
        dots: false,
        infinite: true,
        centerMode: true,
        centerPadding: '40px',
        slidesToShow: 5,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        lazyLoad: 'ondemand',
        asNavFor: '.slider-for',
        focusOnSelect:true
      });
      $('.slider-for').slick({
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        arrows: false,
        fade: true,
        asNavFor: '.regular'
      });
    });
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Now I realise the error in the above is because it is using the same Javascript function to affect the "different" sections and thus causing the error. One fix I can think of is to have a new function for each class, i.e.:

```
$('.regular1').slick({ ... }); -> <section class="regular1">
$('.slider-for1').slick({ ... }); -> <section class="slider-for1">

$('.regular2').slick({ ... }); -> <section class="regular2">
$('.slider-for2').slick({ ... }); -> <section class="slider-for2">

$('.regular3').slick({ ... }); -> <section class="regular3">
$('.slider-for3').slick({ ... }); -> <section class="slider-for3">

etc
```

My question is: Is there a way to do this more efficiently. For example, by including some sort of variable in the class name, i.e:

```
$('.regular'.$a).slick({ ... }); -> <section class="regular1">
$('.slider-for'.$a).slick({ ... }); -> <section class="slider-for1">
```

This isn't a huge issue with only 2 sliders on the page, but I intend to have 10's of sliders on a single page being autogenerated by a PHP script, and I don't really want to have to copy the fucntion over and over again with a different class name, it's inefficient.

For reference, I'm using this carousel: http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

Thanks

Itai

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with `.each()` or `ForEach`, simple example:

```
$( ".slider-for" ).each(function() {
  $( this ).slick({ ... });
});
```

For reference: https://api.jquery.com/each/

Comment: Thanks Rav. I've used the .each function and got it working with the carousel, however, I'm stumped as to how to get the "asNavFor" bit to cross-reference too as they are two different for loops.

    $( ".regular" ).each(function(index) {
          $( this ).slick({
            ...
            asNavFor: '.slider-for',
            ...
          });
      });
      $( ".slider-for" ).each(function(index) {
          $( this ).slick({
          ...
          });
       });

I've tried using index and renaming the classes, but didn't get that right.

Comment: If you want it pretty, define config object with all data within {...}, then call one loop with `$( this ).slick(config);`. Then add attribute and call second loop same way.

Comment: For example `config = {
        dots: false,
        infinite: true,
        centerMode: true,
        centerPadding: '40px',
        slidesToShow: 5,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        lazyLoad: 'ondemand',
        focusOnSelect:true
      }` and after you do `config.asNavFor = '.slider-for'`

Comment: Thanks mate. Your answer got me there! I used the config variable and also defined a "NavFor" array, looped through the "slider-for" class first and assigned "this" each time to a new Array element using the index of the .each and then looped through the "regular" class with the config.asNavFor assigning it each time to the corresponding Array index :) ... Not the prettiest code in the world, but it will work for a prototype :D

Answer (score 0):

This is what the final Javascript looked like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on('ready', function() {
  var config = { dots: false,
                 infinite: true,
                 centerMode: true,
                 centerPadding: '40px',
                 slidesToShow: 5,
                 slidesToScroll: 1,
                 lazyLoad: 'ondemand',
                 focusOnSelect:true
               };
  var navFor = [];
  $( ".slider-for" ).each(function(index) {
      $( this ).slick({
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        arrows: false,
        fade: true,
        swipe: false,
        touchMove: false,
        draggable: false
      });
      navFor[index] = this;
  });
  $( ".regular" ).each(function(index) {
      config.asNavFor = navFor[index];
      $( this ).slick(config);
      //console.log(this);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use multiple slick sliders in one page, leverage `$(this)`, but if you are using slick events too, you can get help below:

```
var slider = $(".bhi-slider"),
    status = $('.slider-number'),
    progressBarLabel = $( '.slider__label' );

slider.each(function(index){
    $(this).slick({
        infinite: true,
        dots: false,
        autoplay: true,
        arrows: true,
        speed: 300,
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        nextArrow: $('.next-slide')[index],
        prevArrow: $('.prev-slide')[index],
    });

    $(this).on('init', function(slick){
        $(progressBarLabel[index]).css('width', 100 / slick.isTrigger + '%');
    });

    $(this).on('beforeChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){ 
        var constNum = ( (1) / (slick.slideCount) ) * 100;
        var calc = ( (nextSlide) / (slick.slideCount) ) * 100;
            calc += constNum;
        $(progressBarLabel[index]).css('width', calc + '%');
    });

    $(this).on('init reInit afterChange', function (event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){
        var i = (currentSlide ? currentSlide : 0) + 1;
        $(status[index]).html('<span class="number-slide">' + i + '</span><span class="total-slide">' + slick.slideCount + '</span>');
    });
});
```